# Loop to add column in DataFrame Pandas ERROR

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new column in my df using a loop. Once it's done, I receive the following error message:

**TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'**

The code I'm trying is the follow:

```
 # Create a list to store the data
estrat = []

# For each row in the column,
for row in cov19['cases']:
    # if more than a value,
    if row < 10:
        # Append a letter grade
        cov19.append('Very Low')
    # else, if more than a value,
    elif row > 10 and row < 50:
        # Append a letter grade
        cov19.append('Low')
    # else, if more than a value,
    elif row > 50 and row < 100:
        # Append a letter grade
        cov19.append('Medium')
    # else, if more than a value,
    elif row > 100 and row < 1000:
        # Append a letter grade
        cov19.append('High')
    # else, if more than a value,
    else:
        # Append a failing grade
        cov19.append('Very High')

# Create a column from the list
cov19['estrat'] = estart
```

Any help? 
Thanks,

Comment: Hello, which line throw an exception ?

Comment: ----> 7     if row < 10:

Answer (score 0):

Your data `row` are stored as text. You need to convert to `int` type before testing it.

This can be done using:

```py
if int(row) < 10:
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried your solution and I got this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '134.0'

Comment: well, your data are not `int` but float. Then simply uses `if float(row) < 10:`

Comment: After use the `if float(row) < 10:`, I got another error: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'str'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid. Column type is 'float64'.